# iterate arrays in python and delete those file if it exists

Tags: python, file-io, delete-file

I have a Python script as shown below which reads four files and give the difference between those files for each `clientId` and it works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, re, json

with open(sys.argv[1]) as old_primary, open(sys.argv[2]) as new_primary, \
    open(sys.argv[3]) as old_second, open(sys.argv[4]) as new_second:

    prepare_json = lambda f: json.loads(re.sub(r'([0-9]+)=', '"\\1":', f.read())) 
    old_pr_data = prepare_json(old_primary)
    new_pr_data = prepare_json(new_primary)
    old_snd_data = prepare_json(old_second)
    new_snd_data = prepare_json(new_second)

    k = sys.argv[5]
    print('ClientId ' + k)
    print('pri=({})'.format(' '.join(map(str, set(old_pr_data[k]) ^ set(new_pr_data[k])))))
    print('snd=({})\n'.format(' '.join(map(str, set(old_snd_data[k]) ^ set(new_snd_data[k])))))
```

Here is how I am running it:

```
python test.py old_primary_mapping.txt new_primary_mapping.txt old_secondary_mapping.txt new_secondary_mapping.txt 1
```

**Problem Statement**

This is the output I get for `clientId 1` after running above script:

```
ClientId 1
pri=(192 196 176)
snd=(1482 1485 1491 1494)
```

Now I want to iterate `pri` and `snd` array and make a file string like as shown below and delete those files if it exists. I am having `*` regex in the file.

For pri, delete these files:

```
/primary/proc_192_for_*.log
/primary/proc_196_for_*.log
/primary/proc_176_for_*.log
```

For snd, delete these files:

```
/secondary/proc_1482_for_*.log
/secondary/proc_1485_for_*.log
/secondary/proc_1491_for_*.log
/secondary/proc_1494_for_*.log
```

I just need to make sure that I am deleting these files only what is there in `pri` and `snd` array. Is this possible to do in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete those files by using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) like (untested):

```
for dir_name, numbers in (('primary', pri), ('secondary', snd)):
    for number in numbers:
        for filename in glob.glob('/{}/proc_{}_for_*.log'.format(dir_name, number)):
             os.unlink(filename)
```

Comment: When I run this, I get an error like this `NameError: name 'pri' is not defined`

Comment: yeah I just realized it. So how can I do this in my case? I dont have proper array since I am just printing it out.

Comment: try `map(int ...` instead of `(map(str ...` or just don't call the `join` to get a list.

Comment: after making that change, I get this error `print('pri=({})'.format(' '.join(map(int, set(old_pr_data[k]) ^ set(new_pr_data[k])))))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`

Comment: don't do the `join`.